# Create citation and url in post using 3 custom fields with conditions for each field... So close!

Tags: custom-field, conditional-content

I am creating a new baseball blog. When submitting a post, I want Authors to cite their source for a news type of post.

I have created a custom meta box with three custom fields:

- Source title, the title of the source. Field name - source_title
- Source URL, the URL of the source. Field name - source_url
- Source name, the name of the person or website of the information.
  Field name - source_name

I want to display every bit of information the Author gives, so credit goes where it is deserved.

The output of the code (with all fields present) will be something like:

```
<h3><a href="source_url">source_title</a> | source_name</h3>
```

When the source_url is entered, but not source_title, the output should be:

```
<h3><a href="source_url">source_url</a> | source_name</h3>
```

(it would be nice to trim the source_url to 25 or so characters and remove http:// if possible)

Through searching and help elsewhere, this is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
$seperator = '';

$name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'source_name', true);
$url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'source_url', true);
$title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'source_title', true);

if($title != '' || $name != '' || ($url != '' && $title != '')){
  $output = '<h3>Source: ';
  $output .= ($url != '' && $title != '') ? '<a href="'.$url.'">': '';
  if($title != '' && $name != '') {
  $seperator = ' | ';
}
  $output .=  $title;
  $output .= ($url != '' && $title != '') ? '</a>': '';
  $output .= $seperator.$name;
  echo $output . '</h3>';
}
?>
```

**What works:**

- When all three fields are entered everything is perfect.
- When title and name are entered, but not url everything is perfect.
- When title and url are entered, but not name everything is perfect.
- When only name is entered everything is perfect
- When only title is entered everything is perfect

**The problems:**

- When url and name are entered but no title, only the name shows.

In this case, I would like to display:

```
<h3><a href="source_url">source_url</a> | source_name</h3>
```

- Similar is true when only the url is entered (no title or name), nothing shows.

In this case, I would like to display:

```
<h3><a href="source_url">source_url</a></h3>
```

Thanks in advance for helping out this novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm meeting all of your requirements here, but I think this might work.

```
<div class="source">
<?php

$name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sourcename', true);
$url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sourceurl', true);
$title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sourcetitle', true);

$snippet = str_replace( "http://", "", $url );
$snippet = substr( $snippet, 0, 22 ) . "...";

if ( !empty( $title ) && !empty( $name ) && !empty( $url ) )
    $output = '<h3 class="cite"><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a> | ' . $name . '</h3>';
else if ( !empty( $name ) && !empty( $url ) )
    $output = '<h3 class="cite"><a href="' . $url . '">' . $name .  '</a></h3>';
else if ( !empty( $title ) && !empty( $url ) )
    $output = '<h3 class="cite"><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></h3>';
else if ( !empty( $title ) && !empty( $name ) )
    $output = '<h3 class="cite">' . $title . ' | ' . $name . '</h3>';
else if ( !empty( $title ) )
    $output = '<h3 class="cite">' . $title . '</h3>';
else if ( !empty( $name ) )
    $output = '<h3 class="cite">' . $name . '</h3>';
else if ( !empty( $url ) )
    $output = '<h3 class="cite"><a href="' . $url . '">' . $snippet . '</a></h3>';
else
    $output = '';

echo $output;

?>
</div>
```

Let me know if it doesn't!

Comment: dunc, thanks for the reply. I replaced my entire code listed above with your code. Unfortunately, nothing displays at all with your code. Also, there is a missing semi-colon at the end of `$output = '<h3><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a> | ' . $name . '</h3>'`

Comment: Code amended - try now :)

Comment: Looks like it is also missing requirements for url, title & title, url & title only

Comment: Can you list those again with semi-colons? Do you mean url; title & ?; title only?

Comment: Sorry, I realized it was confusing after I submitted the comment. Still need requirements for: url title; title name; title; name. Also, the final else should just be an empty display, in case the Author does not enter any citation information.

Comment: dunc, I followed your code example and finished the code myself. I decided that if name, url with no title, I would link the name, rather than display the snippet.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond, was writing my own question, which took a bit of thinking! Glad you got there in the end :)

Comment: no problem... I would rather be led in the right direction, and learn what to do, not just copy and paste. Sad to see that my first question here has a -1. I have bee researching for days... and I think I was very descriptive in my needs.

Comment: The question could've been a little clearer, but it was descriptive and detailed. I don't agree with the downvote, and it's frustrating when someone downvotes you without mentioning why. I have +1'd you. I hope you continue to use WPSE :)